# uploading multiple files to s3 with sailsjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, amazon-s3

I am not using the package of `multer` because I am  not using express so I am not sure how  multer can work with `sailsjs`

Anyways, I am trying to upload multiple files to s3, at first I worked with `for loop` which did not work because for loop is synchronous and file upload is asynchronous.

But then I googled that using recurrsive would work so I tried it but somehow it still didn't though.

Files are uploaded but then the size isn't right for all of them.
Somehow the size might be bigger / smaller then when I download the file let's say if it's a doc file, either I get error saying it's not a msdoc file or what's inside is all scrambled.  If it's a pdf, it'll say failed to open the pdf file.

If I try only with one file, it works sometimes but not always though.

Did I do something wrong with the codes below?

```
s3_upload_multi: async function(req){
    try {
        let fieldName = req._fileparser.upstreams[0].fieldName;
        let files = req.file(fieldName)._files;
        let return_obj = [];

        const upload_rec = files => {
            if (files.length <= 0) return return_obj;
            const f = files.pop();
            const fileUpload = f.stream;

            const s3 = new AWS.S3();
            // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property
            s3.putObject(({  // uses s3 sdk
                Bucket: sails.config.aws.bucket,
                Key: 'blahblahblahblahblah',
                Body: fileUpload._readableState.buffer.head.data,  // buffer from file
                ACL: 'public-read',
              }, function ( err, data ) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                
                return_obj.push(data);
                console.log(return_obj, 'return_obj');
            });

            return upload_rec(files);
        };

        upload_rec(files);


    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, 'inside UploadService');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advices and suggestions

Comment: Have you tried this one https://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads/uploading-to-s-3 ?

Comment: @Saroj that was the first thing I tried because I was using it's original way of file upload but did not work. Which is try I thought of using the aws' own sdk and did some googling.  Ended up I have another post and someone told me to read another skipper's documentation which helped me out